# See the contract code in Meta Mask or/and Ganache

Tags: metamask, truffle-contract, ganache

I have set up `Ganache` and `Meta Mask` on my browser and I have deployed a sample contract in it.
Just follow the steps mentioned in 
https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop.

As far as I found out I (as `Ethereum` user) I should be able to see the contract before confirm any transaction.

Now back to tutorial environment ( `Ganche` and `Meta Mask`):

- Is it possible to use `Meta Mask` to see the actual contract?
- Is it possible to use `Ganache` to see the actual contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the contract source code, then it is not available through Metamask or Ganache.

Take a look here: [Special transaction: Contract creation](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/transactions.asciidoc#special-transaction-contract-creation)

When you submit a transaction to create a contract on the blockchain, you only send the compiled bytecode of the contract. This is enough for the Ethereum Virtual Machine to understand what to do when running the program, but will not be human readable.

3rd party services like [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract) provide the ability for users to paste the source code for a specific contract, and verify that it matches the bytecode, but this is all external from the blockchain.

Other than that, the only real thing you will have access to when interacting with a contract is the [contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/smart-contracts.asciidoc#ethereum-contract-application-binary-interface-abi), which is human readable, but will not define the specific inner workings of the functions.